# Add the user to a role in Oracle Business intelligence from a script

Tags: oracle, weblogic-10.x, obiee

In Oracle Business Intelligence (OBIEE) we can add a user to the specific role by logging to the em and add the user to the specific role in security.

For example:
In
http://slc03lmn.us.oracle.com:7001/em

In WebLogicDomain -> bifoundation_domain ->Security ->Application Roles 
Search for OBI roles and add the user to the role.

We do this manually.

I want to automate this from a python script. Explored the Weblogic scripts but could not find a solution.
Any inputs will be helpful

Comment: @better_use_mkstemp any idea ?

Comment: Is this the type of thing you are looking for? http://weblogic-wonders.com/weblogic/2010/11/10/wlst-script-to-add-users-groups-and-modify-roles/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with a [WLST script](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/config_scripting/using_WLST.html) using the [grantAppRole command](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13813/custom_infra_security.htm#WLSTC1394) like the following:

```
connect(“weblogic”,”welcome1″,”localhost:7001″)
grantAppRole(“obi”,”ReportWLSTRole”,”oracle.security.jps.service.policystore.ApplicationRole”,”BIAuthor”)
grantAppRole(“obi”,”ReportWLSTRole”,”weblogic.security.principal.WLSUserImpl”,”weblogic”)
grantAppRole(“obi”,”ReportWLSTRole”,”weblogic.security.principal.WLSGroupImpl”,”BIAdministrators”)
```

This example shows how to assign a group, a user and a role to the "ReportWLSTRole".
(Example taken from the [RittmanMead blog](http://www.rittmanmead.com/2011/04/oracle-bi-ee-11g-migrating-security-policy-store-part-2/))

Does it have to be a python script?
You can automate this with an init block on the RPD:

Create a table that contains the mapping between users and application roles and then create a row-wise init block for the ROLES variable in the RPD, for example:

```
select 'ROLES', p.rolename from p roles_table  where p.user=':USER'
```

Comment: I need to execute the  action mentioned from a script only. Cannot touch the rpd

Comment: Edited to include a scripting alternative

Comment: I am using this grantAppRole("obi","BISystem","weblogic.security.principal.WLSUserImpl","orcladmin")
this is to give orcladmin user BISystem role. This throws the "error cannot add principal to application role."

And orcladmin is coming from an external authenticator. This is working for other users in the external authenticator but now working just for this user.Any idea about how to make it work ?

Comment: Please include the error code, there are 4 error codes with that description and each has different causes: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/core.1111/e10113/chapter_jps_messages.htm JPS-04120 to JPS-04123

Comment: This is the error message when i try to give BISystem role to orcladmin from external authenticator.

"javax.management.MBeanException: javax.management.MBeanException: Cannot add principal to application role. "